# Unable to configure .htcaccess with Apache2

Tags: apache, apache2

I have been trying, for the good part of two hours, to configure apache2 to use .htcaccess.

Here's my configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin MY_EMAIL
    DocumentRoot /var/www/MY_DOMAIN/public_html
    ServerName MY_DOMAIN
    ServerAlias www.MY_DOMAIN
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

    <Directory /var/www/MY_DOMAIN/public_html>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName SUB_DOMAIN.MY_DOMAIN
    DocumentRoot /var/www/MY_DOMAIN/SUB_DOMAIN
    <Directory /var/www/MY_DOMAIN/SUB_DOMAIN>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is my `.htcaccess` (located in `/var/www/MY_DOMAIN/public_html/.htcaccess`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

If I visit `MY_DOMAIN/header`, I receive a 404 Error. However, `MY_DOMAIN/header.php` works fine.

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm where the `.htaccess` is located? You've also not closed your `<Directory>` in the second virtual host, unlikely to cause the problem but still should be closed.

Comment: Woops, it is closed in the actual file but I didn't copy it exactly :P. Anyway, I've updated my question to show where it's located (`/var/www/MY_DOMAIN/public_html/.htcaccess`).

Comment: Can't see anything obviously wrong with your config and just tested it myself and it worked. Does the 404 come say that `header.php` can't be found? At least you would know the rewrite is working if it did. You could also try enabling the `RewriteLog`

Comment: It says that "The requested URL /header was not found on this server.". I don't think the rewrite is working. I also have used `a2enmod rewrite`, so the mod is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you naming the file ".htaccess" or ".ht**c**access"

If you are not naming the file properly, that is probably the problem.

I think you're looking for ".htaccess"